# How to calc a column Value in DataFrame with condition, on all Rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
A    B
xy   9
xc   34
xz   3
```

How can I do with `pandas`,

```
if df[B] < 90, then df[B] = df[B]*10
```

which would result in the following DataFrame

```
A    B
xy   90
xc   340
xz   30
```

Comment: What's the type of A ?

Comment: just a string of text, for example the name of a bank...

Comment: Your statement is a bit confusing.  xy is one row.  Yet, you multiplied all rows by 10.

Comment: You cannot compare a text to a number

Comment: How can you expect `'xy' < 90` to be a valid comparison?

Comment: I meant - if the value of `B` in `xy < 90`

Comment: @sgerbhctim That still doesn't make any sense. Where is B in `xy < 90`?

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you can do something like this:

```
df.loc[(df.A == "xy") & (df.B<90),"B"] = df.B*10
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
df.loc[(df["A"] == "xy") & (df["B"] <90),"B"] = df.B*10
```

In general, use loc to define where you want to change a dataframe then assign the new values. here is a general example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[10,4],[5,4]], columns=["A","B"])
>>> df
    A  B
0   1  2
1  10  4
2   5  4
>>> df.loc[df.A <5,:]
   A  B
0  1  2
>>> df.loc[df.A <5,"B"] = df.B*10 
>>> df 
    A   B
0   1  20
1  10   4
2   5   4
>>> df
```

#### Edit

Based on your questions in the comments below, here's what you can do, to perform `df.B*10` on all the column if the condition `(df["A"] == "xy") & (df["B"] <90)` is valid for any row:

```
if any((df["A"] == "xy") & (df["B"] <90)):
    df.B = df.B*10
```

Comment: What if `A` is actually named `Bank Name`

Comment: @sgerbhctim you change the column `A` with the column `Bank Name`

Comment: `df.loc[(df.Bank Name == "xy") & (df.B<90),"B"] = df.B*10 ` would give me an error.

Comment: @sgerbhctim do this `df.loc[(df["Bank Name"] == "xy") & (df.B<90),"B"] = df.B*10`

Comment: Getting an issue.. this is the code snippet I am using: `df.loc[(df['Bank Name'] == 'Merrill Lynch') & (df['This Wk'] < 1000000), 'This Wk'] = df['This Wk']*10`.. the only issue here is, that it only affects the one Merrill Lynch value and not the others.. is there a simple fix?

Comment: I need it to multiply the entire columns 'This Wk' by 10.

Comment: This different from what you had in your question.. try something like if any(df.A == 'xy') ..

Comment: you are the best. Thank you.

Comment: @sgerbhctim you are welcome. If this is a sufficient answer, consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'xy') & (df['B'] < 90), 'B']*=10
```

This gives you

```
    A   B
0   xy  90
1   xc  34
2   xz  3
```

This doesn't match your desired output as your problem statement says if the value of B in xy < 90

If you wish to get the output df you have posted, simply use

```
df.loc[(df['B'] < 90), 'B']*=10
```

And you get

```
    A   B
0   xy  90
1   xc  340
2   xz  30
```

Answer (score 0):

`loc` is a good way to do this

```
df.loc[(df.A=='xy')&(df.B<90),'B'] = 10*df.loc[(df.A=='xy')&(df.B<90),'B']
```

What this says is essentially, where ever A is xy, select the B column and multiply it by 10.

Comment: so essentially, I should add the if statement before.. how would I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try

```
df.B=np.where(df.B<90,df.B*10,df.B)

    A   B
0   xy  90
1   xc  340
2   xz  30
```

For you additional:

```
df.B*(np.where(df.loc[df.A=='xy','B']<90,10,1))
```

Comment: I meant for my question to say... ok if the `B` value of `A=xy` is `<90`, then multiply the whole coluumn `B` by 10.

Comment: Sadly that didnt do anything... the closest I have gotten was @MedAli answer... can you look at my comments there and see what I can change? Would really really appreciate it.

Comment: @sgerbhctim I get confused df['B']*(np.where(df.loc[df['A']=='xy','B']<90,10,1)) ?

Comment: @sgerbhctim try it , if MedAli 's answer work , mine should as well